# React conditional re-rendering not working using functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can someone explain why "condition" is not triggering re-render when it is changed when the response is received and state is set?

When this code is run, it always redirects to "/unauthorized/login" even when the response is true. I thought page is always re-rendered when the state is changed.

```
const PrivateRoute = props => {
const [condition, setCondition] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    if (!condition) {
        getUserAccess();
    }
}, [condition]);

const getUserAccess = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("/some-api");
    const status = response.data; /* status will either be true or false */
    setCondition(status);
}

return condition ? (<Route path={props.path} exact={props.exact} component={props.component}/>) :
    (<Redirect to="/unauthorized/login"/>); 
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Comment: Is the `condition` state updated to a truthy value? What is the value of `status`?

Comment: Why do you set empty string in initial data in `useState()`? It must be `false` or `true` for conditional

Comment: @Danial [Falsey values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) are also ok to use in boolean expressions.

Comment: The value of status will either be true or false. I have updated the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 3):

You should/could use a third "pending" state that is neither explicitly true or false, and wait for the GET request to resolve. Without this the private route component doesn't wait for the resolved state and uses the falsey (`''`) initial `condition` state and renders the redirect.

```
const PrivateRoute = props => {
  const [condition, setCondition] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!condition) {
      getUserAccess();
    }
  }, [condition]);

  const getUserAccess = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("/some-api");
      setCondition(response.data);
    } catch(err) {
      // handle any error logging, etc..
      setCondition(false); // clear "loading state" so redirect can happen
    }
  }

  if (condition === null) {
    return <Spinner />; // or any other "pending" UI indication
  }

  return condition ? (
    <Route {...props} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to="/unauthorized/login"/>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

### **It's because your `condition` is `!'' = false` in the initial render.**

So it's always got to your 2nd condition: `<Redirect to="/unauthorized/login"/>` without having a chance for `useEffect` to run.

**To solve this, you will need to have a `loading` indicator to let your component know that you are waiting for the response:**

Something like this:

```
const PrivateRoute = props => {
const [condition, setCondition] = useState('');
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!condition) {
        getUserAccess();
    }
}, [condition]);

const getUserAccess = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("/some-api");
    const status = response.data; /* status will either be true or false */
    setCondition(status);
    setIsLoading(false);
}

if (isLoading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;

return condition ? (<Route path={props.path} exact={props.exact} component={props.component}/>) :
    (<Redirect to="/unauthorized/login"/>); 
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

Axios is promise based library

```
const [condition, setCondition] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
        if (!condition) {
            axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
            .then( (response) =>{
                //console.log(response.data)
                setCondition(response.data)
            })
            .catch(
                (error)=>{
                    console.log(error);
                }
            )
        }
    }, [condition]);
```

Comment: Condition is still initially false and the redirect will be rendered. You've only converted `async/await` to a Promise chain. You are correct though that any errors or rejected promises should probably be caught.

Comment: Tq for pointing me, i think catch block holds all the stuff you raised, but my main concern is to **setCondition()**